# Bitcoin testnet addresses

Tags: testnet, ethereum

Why bitcoin addresses in testnet are not the same as in mainnet? For example ethereum address in mainnet can be used in testnet's (ropsten, rinkeby).

Answer (score 1):

Because using the same addresses for both is an enormous footgun. People could accidentally send funds on the wrong chain.

Comment: sounds counterintuitive. had the same address been used on both "chains", it would be a simple 1:1